# Having trouble understanding example 10.2 of Kleppner and Kolenkow

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, reference-frames, vectors

The following is from Kleppner and Kolenkow's Introduction to Mechanics example 10.2:

> Suppose that a comet with E > 0 (an extrasolar comet) drifts into the
> solar system. From our discussion of the energy diagram for motion
> under a gravitational force, the comet will approach the Sun and then
> swing away, never to return. How then can an extrasolar comet with
> initial energy E > 0 become a member of the solar system? For this to
> happen, its energy would have to be decreased to a negative value.
> However, the gravitational force is conservative and the total energy
> of the comet in the Sun’s gravity cannot change.
>
> Suppose that an extrasolar comet is heading outward toward the orbit
> of Jupiter after swinging around the Sun, as shown in the sketch. Let
> the velocity of the comet before it starts to interact appreciably
> with Jupiter be vi, and let Jupiter’s velocity be $\textbf{V}$. For simplicity we
> shall assume that the orbits are not appreciably deflected by the Sun
> during the time of interaction.
>
> In the comet–Jupiter center of mass system Jupiter is essentially at
> rest because of its much greater mass, and the center of mass velocity
> of the comet is $\textbf{v}_{ic} = \textbf{v}_i − \textbf{V}$, as shown in (a).
>
> [image]
>
> In the center of mass system the path of the comet is deflected by
> Jupiter, but the final speed is equal to the initial speed $\textbf{v}_{ic}$. Hence,
> the interaction merely rotates $\textbf{v}_{ic}$ through some angle Θ to a new
> direction $\textbf{v}_{fc}$, as shown in (b). The final velocity in the space-fixed
> system is $$\textbf{v}_f = \textbf{v}_{fc} + \textbf{V}.$$
>
> Figure (c) shows $\textbf{v}_f$ and, for comparison, $\textbf{v}_i$. For the deflection shown,
> $\textbf{v}_f < \textbf{v}_i$, and the comet’s energy has decreased. Conversely, if the
> deflection is in the opposite direction, interaction with Jupiter
> would increase the energy, possibly freeing a bound comet from the
> solar system.

The author further says:

> The process we have described may seem to contradict the idea that the
> gravitational force is strictly conservative. Only gravity acts on the
> comet and yet its total energy can change. The reason is that the
> comet experiences a time-dependent gravitational force, and
> time-dependent forces are intrinsically non-conservative.

How exactly is this time dependent? Doesn't the potential energy still depend on the separation vector between the Sun and the comet, and the separation vector between the comet and Jupiter? Also, as a consequence does this mean that the gravitational force experienced by a particle in a three (or higher) body central force problem is time dependent?

On a different note, the vector diagram here looks very similar to the vector diagrams I see in scattering problems where the target particle is much much more massive than the projectile  and the two particles are interacting under a central force. But as far as I know, the two particles shouldn't be exchanging energy. So what really is the difference in vector diagrams between the two cases when viewed from the center of mass frame?

Comment: Two things: 1) Having large blocks of text in an image means that text won't be searchable by people looking for this question. If you can, please type out the relevant text (including the diagrams as images is fine). 2) It seems like you may have paraphrased some relevant context when you say, "The author said that this only happens when there is a third body like Jupiter and if there were only the Sun and the comet around, then there wouldn't be any exchange of energy like this." Can you include what the author actually says instead?

Comment: done @probably_someone

Answer (score 0):

> How exactly is this time dependent?

The problem has been formulated so that the comet is a point particle moving through the gravitational field produced by the Sun and by Jupiter.

We can work in the center of mass frame of the Sun, so the sun isn't moving, and therefore the gravitational potential of the Sun is time independent.

However, in this frame, Jupiter is moving, since Jupiter orbits the Sun. In panel (a) of the figure you posted in the question, we can see that Jupiter is moving with velocity $\textbf{V}$. Therefore, the gravitational potential of the Sun+Jupiter system is time dependent.

> Doesn't the potential energy still
> depend on the separation vector between the Sun and the comet, and the
> separation vector between the comet and Jupiter?

Exactly. But, in the center of mass frame of the Sun, the separation vector between Jupiter and a fixed point $x$ will depend on time, since Jupiter is moving.

> Also, as a
> consequence does this mean that the potential energy of a particle in
> a three (or higher) body central force problem is time dependent?

I am not sure I understand.  The potential energy of a particle in a central force potential *is* time dependent -- the potential energy decreases as the particle falls into the potential well, and increases as it climbs out. This has nothing to do with considerations about Jupiter -- the potential energy of a comet orbiting the Sun is time dependent (unless the comet is somehow on a circular orbit).

> On a different note, the vector diagram here looks very similar to the
> vector diagrams I see in scattering problems where the target particle
> is much much more massive than the projectile and the two particles
> are interacting under a central force. But as far as I know, the two
> particles shouldn't be exchanging energy. So what really is the
> difference in vector diagrams between the two cases when viewed from
> the center of mass frame?

If you like, you can think of this problem as two particles (comet+Jupiter) interacting via a central force (the gravitational force between the comet and Jupiter). This scattering process happens in the vicinity of a third body, the Sun. I suspect the similarity to problems you have seen before comes from this view of the comet-Jupiter scattering as a two-body problem; the figure shows only the comet and Jupiter and moves into the comet-Jupiter COM frame. However, since this event takes place in vicinity of the Sun, which also contributes to the potential energy, the comet-Jupiter scattering problem is not equivalent to the comet and Jupiter scattering in empty space, with no Sun present. Of course I don't know what scattering problems you have studied, but I hope this helps to explain the similarities and differences with problems you may have seen before.

Finally, I will just mention that fundamentally, the laws of Newtonian gravity are time *in*dependent, and energy of the whole system is conserved. If one treats this as a three body problem, then one can say that the comet's energy has been "dissipated" by "heating up" the Jupiter-Sun system. However, the point of view of a point-like comet moving in a time dependent potential is correct and very convenient, for this problem.

Comment: When I said that potential energy is time dependent, I meant it explicitly depends on time. "the potential energy decreases as the particle falls into the potential well, and increases as it climbs out" - if I take this view then doesn't the author's claim that "the comet experiences a time-dependent gravitational force" in this case become unnecessary because the same is true when there are just two bodies? If the comet is not in a circular orbit around the Sun, then it would experience different gravitational forces at different times regardless of whether there is a third body or not.

Comment: In the comet-Sun system, the potential energy of the particle is time dependent, but the gravitational potential through which the particle is moving is time independent. In the comet-Jupiter-Sun system, the potential energy of the particle is, once again, time dependent. The new feature is that the *gravitational potential* through which the particle is moving is time dependent. This last point is why energy is not conserved.

Comment: What do you mean when you say potential energy? The effective potential?

Comment: The potential energy of the comet at time $t$, is the mass of the comet, times the gravitational potential evaluated at the position of the comet at time $t$.

Comment: In scattering problems when viewed from the com frame, the velocity vectors rotate by a scattering angle exactly like that shown in the image. If I follow the same geometrical logic given in the example then the final and initial velocities won't have the same magnitude in the laboratory frame. That's what I meant

Comment: Also why doesn't the comet's energy change in the com frame? Since $v_{ic}$ and $v_{fc}$ have the same magnitude, in the cm frame the KE should be unchanged right?

Comment: There are two processes happening, on different timescales. The first is the comet orbiting the Sun, on a very long and slow time scale. The second is the interaction with Jupiter, which is comparatively fast and essentially instantaneous. The second process, as you have noted, is really the same mathematically as if the Jupiter and the comet were interacting in empty space. From that point of view, we could analyze the comet-Jupiter scattering in any frame of reference, so why not use the COM frame. I agree with both statements you have made about this problem: (contd)

Comment: (...) the initial and final velocities of the comet are different in the lab frame, and the KE in the COM frame is unchanged. We can also understand the first, slower process in any frame, but by far the easiest frame to work in is the "lab" frame (ie the Sun's frame). In the Sun frame, as you have pointed out, the interaction with Jupiter reduces the magnitude of the comet's velocity. This changes how the comet will orbit around the sun. If the speed is reduced enough, then the comet's KE can fall below the binding energy of the Sun, and it will fall into a bound orbit.